# Can a transporter follow an 'material' agent into another agent?

Tags: anylogic

I have an material agent that is moved from the Main agent to inside another agent (simulating a room). I can send the material agent using the Exit and Enter blocks. The 'room' agent contains a network that the material agent is being sent to.

The material agent is initially being moved in Main using a Transporter. However I'm not able to get this Transporter to follow the material agent into the room agent. The main questions is - is it possible to send a Transporter into another agent? Or does it need to remain in the agent that the Transporter Fleet is located?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I will correct benjamin by saying that with setEnvironment you can't do it since that's a function that is called on the agent initialization.

Instead of setEnvironment,something you do normally is to send the agent to a new population (which is the way you dynamically change environment), but it doesn't work with transporters

My answer would be that you can't do it since transporters who follow paths are defined as strict AGVs and can only move on their initial network and you can't change the network, unlike other agents.

But i'm always a bit suspicious of myself when i say something is not possible...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will think of a better way to set this up

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with some `setEnvironment()` calls.

However, it is not a good setup. Think of reality: your rooms are spatially all part of the same environment: your flat (or factory or whatever). Moving from 1 room to the next does not mean you change your flat. You stay in the same environment.

You should setup your room agents like that as well: their spatial representation should reside in Main (or whatever agent they are embedded in).

Use a parameter of type `ShapeRectangle` or similar in your Room agent to define which rectangle (or else) represents the spatial aspect of the room.

Then, the flow chart blocks in the Room agent simply refer to that parameter for their spatial needs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will think of a better way to set this up